# How to install the latest version of neovim?

Tags: pi-3b+

The latest stable version of Neovim is 0.4.4. What's the easiest way to install that version of Neovim? Snap, ppa? I've tried building from source but I don't know why `make CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo` doesn't work.

I've tried to install it like this:

```
# Install latest CMake https://stackoverflow.com/a/56690743/13411047
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y libssl-dev
wget -O /tmp/cmake.tar.gz "https://cmake.org/files/v3.19/cmake-3.19.1.tar.gz"
tar -xvzf cmake.tar.gz
rm cmake.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.19.1/
cmake .
make
sudo make install

# Install Neovim
sudo apt-get install libtool libool-bin autoconf automake cmake g++ pkg-config unzip
release=0.4.4
wget -O /tmp/neovim.zip "https://github.com/neovim/neovim/archive/v$release.zip"
cd /tmp
unzip neovim.zip
rm neovim.zip
cd "neovim-$release"
make CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
sudo make install
```

I get:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
    Could NOT find Gettext (missing: GETTEXT_MSGMERGE_EXECUTABLE
    GETTEXT_MSGFMT_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/local/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:577 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    /usr/local/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindGettext.cmake:81 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
    src/nvim/po/CMakeLists.txt:1 (find_package)
```

That error should have been fixed by upgrading CMake but aparently the old CMake isn't the cause of the error.

I finally was able to install it. I hope you can tell me an easier way of installing it. This is what I did:

```
# Build and install neovim for Debian
sudo apt-get install -y \
  autoconf \
  automake \
  cmake \
  g++ \
  gettext \
  libncurses5-dev \
  libtool \
  libtool-bin \
  libunibilium-dev \
  libunibilium4 \
  ninja-build \
  pkg-config \
  python-pip \
  python3-pip \
  software-properties-common \
  unzip

# Enable use of python plugins
pip install setuptools
pip install --upgrade pynvim
pip3 install setuptools
pip3 install --upgrade pynvim

gem install neovim
npm install -g neovim

# Get latest stable Neovim release
git clone https://github.com/neovim/neovim.git "~/neovim"
release=0.4.4
wget -O /tmp/neovim.tar.gz "https://github.com/neovim/neovim/archive/v$release.tar.gz"
cd /tmp
tar -xvzf neovim.tar.gz
rm neovim.tar.gz
cd "neovim-$release"
make CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
sudo make install
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there's that much benefit in using neovim over the latest version of vim. The competition spurred vim's developer to do a lot of work in recent years and now vim is probably the better choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Official documentation recommend using AppImage in any Linux distro:

> The Releases page provides an AppImage that runs on most Linux systems. No installation is needed, just download nvim.appimage and run it. (It might not work if your Linux distribution is more than 4 years old.)

source: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#linux

Raspbian is not "more than 4 years old", but they do not provide ARM binaries in the AppImage (source: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8512).

So, my best solution, avoiding manual building is using snap: https://snapcraft.io/nvim. Apply these commands:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install --classic nvim
```

**Note**: In my Raspberry Pi 4, with current Raspbian Buster, snap binaries are not in `PATH`, even with file `/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh` trying to do so... In any case, neovim is located in `/snap/bin/nvim`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Got me out of the bind :-)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a quick but powerful vim editor after installing a new raspberry pi OS. Open a new terminal window and do the following.

Create a bash alias file
`touch ~/.bash_aliases`

Open that file
`sudo nano ~/.bash_aliases`

and paste the following and ctrl+o and ctrl+x to write and exit

```
pathmunge () {
    if ! echo "$PATH" | grep -Eq "(^|:)$1($|:)"; then
        if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
            PATH="$PATH:$1"
        else
            PATH="$1:$PATH"
        fi
    fi
}

alias installsnap="sudo apt install snapd"
alias installnewerneovim="sudo snap install --classic nvim"
pathmunge "/snap/bin"

alias installnvchad="git clone https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad ~/.config/nvim --depth 1
nvim +'hi NormalFloat guibg=#1e222a' +PackerSync"

setupNvchad () {
  installsnap
  installnewerneovim
  installnvchad
  echo "alias vi=\"nvim\"" >> ~/.bash_aliases
}
```

Force the shell/terminal to reload the bash config
`source ~/.bashrc`

Call the setup function on the cli
`setupNvchad`

Open files with `nvim ~/.bash_aliases`

Then go check out NvChad and how to customize it further.

**Bonus**: Get the fonts/icons to work:

Add the following to your `bash_aliases` file

```
# Nerd fonts
installNerdFonts () {
 mkdir -p ~/Development
 cd ~/Development
 
 if [ ! -d "./nerd-fonts" ] ; then
   git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts.git
 fi 

 cd nerd-fonts

 ./install.sh SpaceMono
}
```

Then close/open your terminal (or source your bash file again) before running `installNerdFonts`

Then close/open your terminal again and nvim should show icons correctly.

Comment: I am seeing that e.g. ~/.config/nvim/init.lua is not being read. does your pathmunge function help with that?